# Add new column that CONCAT's values from past period (date range) respecting groups in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-aggregation

I'm using MS SQL Server 2012 to check if a user has selected a particular genre of movie over a past period of time for each transaction/row.

I want to solve this by CONCAT’ing the past genre into a new column for a given period, e.g. past 12 months, or 6 to 12 months. I’m not concerned with duplicate genres appearing in the new columns.

Then I can run the logic to check if a particular genre was ordered either in SQL or by an external program. Below is an example of the expected output for two customers who ordered videos.

[image: Table of desired result]

Here is the SQL that I used to generate the initial table.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tb1;

CREATE TABLE tbl
    (id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
     PersonName VARCHAR(10),
     OrderDT DATETIME,
     Genre VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO tbl (PersonName, OrderDT, Genre)
VALUES
    ('Bob', '2019-05-01', 'biopic'),
    ('Bob', '2019-10-01', 'drama'),
    ('Bob', '2020-02-01', 'doco, action' ),
    ('Bob', '2020-05-01', 'comedy'),
    ('Bob', '2020-09-01', 'horror'),
    ('Bob', '2020-12-01', 'action, comedy'),
    ('Alice', '2018-03-01', 'comedy, drama'),
    ('Alice', '2018-08-01', 'action'),
    ('Alice', '2018-12-01', 'horror');
```

I understand that using STRING_AGG() and GROUP BY could be used to aggregate rows of values per customer, but I need help to do this for a past period of time and each row.

Even though I’m using MS SQL (through no choice of my own :) ) I’d hope the solution is generic enough to be usable in Postgres or MariaDB. Hence, I’d like to avoid special MS SQL server only commands like STRING_AGG() if possible.

Comment: Although the SQL standard defines a function for string aggregation (`listagg()`) only very few databases support the standard there (I think it's actually only Oracle) so there is no way you can find a DBMS independent solution for this

Comment: yep @a_horse_with_no_name comments is absolute right. Instead of try to avoid command you should just write different version of queries correspond to the DBMS.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was afraid of @a_horse_with_no_name :)

Comment: Do you know the maximum number of genres in the columns?  Do you know all the genres?

Comment: The request to run in all three databases is impossible, simply because the date functions are incompatible.  I don't think there is a way to specify the previous 6 or 12 months in a way that is compatible across databases.  Also `string_agg()` is not supported in SQL Server 2012, so something is amiss in your description.

Comment: Sorry, I was only using string_agg() as an example of a proprietary function that I was hoping to avoid, not specifically within MS SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is hard enough in SQL Server.  You should not be storing multiple genres in a string.  You mention `string_agg()` so you are clearly not using SQL Server 2012.  Here is the logic that works in more recent versions of SQL Server:

```
select t.*, t12.*, t6.*
from tbl t cross apply
     (select string_agg( trim(g.genre), ', ') as orders_12mon
      from (select distinct s.value as genre
            from tbl t2 cross apply
                 string_split(genre, ',') s
            where t2.personname = t.personname and
                  t2.orderdt <= t.orderdt and
                  t2.orderdt > dateadd(month, -12, t.orderdt)
           ) g
     ) t12 cross apply
     (select string_agg( trim(g.genre), ', ') as orders_6mon
      from (select distinct s.value as genre
            from tbl t2 cross apply
                 string_split(genre, ',') s
            where t2.personname = t.personname and
                  t2.orderdt > dateadd(month, -12, t.orderdt) and
                  t2.orderdt <= dateadd(month, -6, t.orderdt)
           ) g
     ) t6;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=da786a247e1f919d52c1177bf433848f) is a db<>fiddle.

This code is highly non-portable.  Here are some reasons:

- Date/time functions are different in different databases.  There is no consistent way to subtract 6 months across the databases you mention.
- SQL Server does not support the `range` keyword with time intervales.
- String processing functions are quite different across the databases, so splitting a string is not standard.

That said, I can think of one arcane approach if you know all the genres in advance.  But that is really messy and there are simpler methods in each database you mention.